# iText datamatrix generation problem

Tags: java, itext, barcode

I am attempting to generate datamatrix barcodes from within itext.  This works fine for most of my codes but not for some codes.  One example is:

> HEnSh0701003-2V1

This produces a non square barcode for some reason.  When I use encoders from other companies (such as IDAutomation)  I do get a valid square barcode.

Does anyone have an idea why this is happening?  I am looking for a solution so I can use the embedded iTest DataMatrix class and not have to use a third party one.

A sample of the code I am using:

```
BarcodeDatamatrix bar = new BarcodeDatamatrix();
 bar.setOptions(BarcodeDatamatrix.DM_AUTO);
bar.generate("HEnSh0701003-2V1");
bcd.addCell(bar.createImage());
```

where bcd is a PdfTable with 2 columns.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ran into this exact issue.  I ended up digging into the iText source code to figure this one out.  iText is resizing the barcode to fit the text you provided.

iText supports the following sizes for datamatrix barcodes:
10x10, 12x12, 8x18, 14x14, 8x32, 16x16, 12x26, 18x18, 20x20, 12x36, 22x22, 16x36, 24x24, 26x26, 16x48, 32x32, 36x36, 40x40, 44x44, 48x48, 52x52, 64x64, 72x72, 80x80, 88x88, 96x96, 104x104, 120x120, 132x132, 144x144

As you can see, there are a number of non-square sizes in there.  What I did was create a list of square barcode sizes and then try each size while checking the return value of the generate() call.

```
// supported square barcode dimensions
int[] barcodeDimensions = {10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20, 22, 24, 26, 32, 36, 40, 44, 48, 52, 64, 72, 80, 88, 96, 104, 120, 132, 144};

BarcodeDatamatrix barcode = new BarcodeDatamatrix();
barcode.setOptions(BarcodeDatamatrix.DM_AUTO);

// try to generate the barcode, resizing as needed.
for (int generateCount = 0; generateCount < barcodeDimensions.length; generateCount++) {
    barcode.setWidth(barcodeDimensions[generateCount]);
    barcode.setHeight(barcodeDimensions[generateCount]);
    int returnResult = barcode.generate(text);
    if (returnResult == BarcodeDatamatrix.DM_NO_ERROR) {
        return barcode.createImage();
    }
}

throw new Exception("Error generating barcode.");
```

Answer (score 3):

Thanks JonMR

For those who need it, here is the same code in VB.net

```
    Private Function GetDataMatrixBarcode(ByVal message As String) As iTextSharp.text.Image

        Dim barcode As BarcodeDatamatrix = New BarcodeDatamatrix()
        Dim barcodeDimensions() As Integer = New Integer() {10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20, 22, 24, 26, 32, 36, 40, 44, 48, 52, 64, 72, 80, 88, 96, 104, 120, 132, 144}
        Dim returnResult As Integer

        barcode.Options = BarcodeDatamatrix.DM_AUTO

        For generateCount As Integer = 0 To barcodeDimensions.Length - 1
            barcode.Width = barcodeDimensions(generateCount)
            barcode.Height = barcodeDimensions(generateCount)
            returnResult = barcode.Generate(message)
            If returnResult = BarcodeDatamatrix.DM_NO_ERROR Then
                Return barcode.CreateImage
            End If
        Next

        Throw New Exception("Error generating datamatrix barcode for text '" & message & "'")

    End Function
```

Answer (score 3):

For those who need it in C#:

```
// supported square barcode dimensions
        int[] barcodeDimensions = { 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20, 22, 24, 26, 32, 36, 40, 44, 48, 52, 64, 72, 80, 88, 96, 104, 120, 132, 144 };

        BarcodeDatamatrix barcode = new BarcodeDatamatrix();
        barcode.Options = (BarcodeDatamatrix.DM_AUTO);

        // try to generate the barcode, resizing as needed.
        for (int generateCount = 0; generateCount < barcodeDimensions.Length; generateCount++)
        {
            barcode.Width = (barcodeDimensions[generateCount]);
            barcode.Height = (barcodeDimensions[generateCount]);
            int returnResult = barcode.Generate("1234567");
            if (returnResult == BarcodeDatamatrix.DM_NO_ERROR)
            {
                Image barcodeImg = barcode.CreateImage();
                table.AddCell(barcodeImg);
                table.AddCell(string.Empty);
            }
        }
```

Btw, does anyone know how to make rectangular barcodes with this? Whenever I choose a rectangular format it gives me an Error code of 3 (DM_Error_Invalid_Square).

Comment: You want something like http://jpgraph.net/download/manuals/chunkhtml/ch26.html#fig.datamatrix-rect

Answer (score 1):

You must change

```
barcode.setOptions(BarcodeDatamatrix.DM_AUTO);
```

to

```
barcode.setOptions(BarcodeDatamatrix.DM_B256);
```

Comment: `DM_B256` gave me a nice 14 pixels x 14 pixels bitmap/png. which I was able to scan with my barcode scanner on android.

Answer (score 1):

Implementation in Java to add barcode to existing pdf file using itext.

Jar files used: itext, commons-codec-1.6.jar

```
InputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(new File("c:/tmp/your_existing.pdf")));
FileOutputStream outStream = new FileOutputStream("c:/tmp/pdf_copy_1.pdf");

PdfContentByte contentByte = null;
        int totalPages = 0;
        PdfReader pdfReader = null;
        PdfStamper pdfStamper = null;

    try {
        pdfReader = new PdfReader(inputStream);
        totalPages = pdfReader.getNumberOfPages();
        pdfStamper = new PdfStamper(pdfReader, outStream);
        String text = "SAMPLE BARCODE TEST";
        String barcodeData = DigestUtils.md5Hex(text); --encoding barcode text...

        //Adding barcode to each page in pdf
        for (int i = 1; i <= totalPages; i++) {
            contentByte = pdfStamper.getOverContent(i);
            if(barcodeData != null){
                Image img = null;
                BarcodeDatamatrix datamatrix = new BarcodeDatamatrix();
                datamatrix.setWidth(10); -- BARCODE WIDTH
                datamatrix.setHeight(10); -- BARCODE HEIGHT
                datamatrix.generate(barcodeData);
                img = datamatrix.createImage();
                img.setAbsolutePosition(175, 750); --barcode position x,y
                contentByte.addImage(img);
            }
        }

    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

    }
```