# iTextSharp datamatrix barcode returns null when setting height/width

Tags: c#, itext, barcode

I'm trying to create a 2d Datamatrix barcode using iTextSharp.  If I don't provide a height or a width, the barcode generates just fine.  However, when I attempt to set the height and width of the barcode, it then returns a null object.

```
        BarcodeDatamatrix barcode = new BarcodeDatamatrix
                                        {
                                            Width = 10,
                                            Height = 10
                                        };

        barcode.Generate(barcodeData);
        Image barcodeImage = barcode.CreateImage();
        return barcodeImage;
    }
```

Why is it returning a null, and how can I get it to set my dimensions?

Comment: There are two different dimensions you need to watch out for: the pixel dimensions of the image and the dimensions in squares of the datamatrix barcode. The latter only accepts specific combinations defined in the spec and it affects how much data you can store in the barcode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out the issue is that I was setting my dimensions smaller than the what was needed for my barcode.  I used the info found here: [iText datamatrix generation problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/775625/itext-datamatrix-generation-problem) to discover my error.

Answer (score 1):

I tested your exact code and didn't have any problem with it.  Did you actually use 10 for both height and width in your code?  When not using one of the allowed dimensions, you'll get the null you mentioned: http://api.itextpdf.com/itext/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/BarcodeDatamatrix.html#setHeight(int)